# Why does pamac bypass sudoers conf?

Tags: sudo, package-management, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro Linux, based off of arch.

#### /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults rootpw
Defaults:%wheel rootpw
%wheel  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Quickly, explaining how I believe this configuration should behave - if the user doesn't have the permissions, then they should be prompted for root's password.

#### Users

| User | Group |
| --- | --- |
| lunarix | wheel/sudo |
| testuser | none |
| root | root |

All works well, except it seems `pamac` is not following my sudoers configuration.

when running `pamac install pip` under the following users

- testuser will allow root-privileges if I type in `lunarix`'s password.
- lunarix will allow root-privileges if I type in `lunarix`'s password.

When installing, `pip` it does install globally for all users.

##### running `sudo -l`

###### testuser

```
Matching Defaults entries for testuser on host:
    insults, rootpw, rootpw

User testuser may run the following commands on host:
    (ALL) ALL
```

###### lunarix

```
Matching Defaults entries for lunarix on host:
    insults, rootpw, rootpw, rootpw

User lunarix may run the following commands on host:
    (ALL) ALL
    (ALL) ALL
```

Why is `pamac` allowing this?

#### Edits

###### syslog

```
Sep 17 06:43:44 masterbook polkitd[560]: Operator of unix-session:2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:lunarix to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.manjaro.pamac.commit for system-bus-name::1.570 [pamac install python-pip] (owned by unix-user:testuser)
Sep 17 06:43:44 masterbook audit[213804]: USER_ACCT pid=213804 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="lunarix" exe="/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success
```

After some investigation and help from @muru, we've determined that polkitd is using [PAM](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/pam.d.5.html) to authenticate. I'll leave the thread open just in case someone who has in depth experience can give guidance on configuration, or best practices for this type of configuration.

Comment: Does `pamac` have anything to do with `sudo` at all? It could be using Polkit instead (and it might be, based on it asking `testuser` for `lunarix`'s password). Can you show the prompt it shows and journal entries from when it prompts you for authentication?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `pamac` to write a proper answer. But [this page](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Pamac#Using_the_Pamac_CLI) instructs not to use `sudo` with `pamac`. `pamac` seems to have its own privilege escalation mechanism that has nothing to do with `sudo` or the sudoers file. However, I can't find a manpage to verify this.

Comment: For the same reason that `sudo` itself runs as root - `/usr/bin/sudo` is owned by root and the setuid bit is set.   `sudo` isn't the source of the ability to run programs as root or other users, that's in the kernel.  `sudo` just provides a flexible way of allowing systems administrators to define WHO is allowed to run WHAT programs as someone else (often as root).   `su` is another such program (and works similarly to the way you have defined your `/etc/sudoers` rules), and `super` is yet another.

Comment: Numerous other programs have the setuid bit set (and manage their own security needs) - e.g `passwd`, `chfn`, `chsh`, `newgrp`, `mount` and `umount`.  and `su` and `sudo`, of course.   Try running `find /bin/ /sbin/ /usr/bin/ /usr/sbin/ -perm /4000 -ls`.   `pamac` will be one of them.

Comment: instead of just `-perm /4000`, that should be `\( -perm /4000 -o -perm /6000 \)` to list files that have either just the setuid or both setuid and setgid bits set.    e.g. `/usr/bin/chage` is setuid root AND setgid shadow, and `/usr/bin/wall` is setuid root and setgid tty.